# On Device Training Tensorflow

Tags: python, java, android, tensorflow, dataset

Is there a way to trained dataset taken from user image while running the apps? Dataset are collected based on images from user(take photo or select from gallery) on apps.

p/s: I found on-device training Tensorflow but based on documentation we have to trained the model in Python first and export to tensorflow. Is there a way to do directly on the apps in Android Studio without going through these?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, to predict with trainable weight, feedback, update weights or load model is possible. You may transfer learning from the current to another model.

There are many libraries including C++, C# wrapper, TFLite, TF and etc.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import pyaudio as pyaudio
import tensorflow as tf

import os
from os.path import exists

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
b_training = True
n_steps = 0

image = [ ]
list_image = [ ]
list_label = [ ]

for i in range(80):
    list_image.append(tf.zeros([ 5, 80 ]).numpy())
    list_label.append(0)

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 8000
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 1
LONG_STEPS = 100000000000

data_1 = tf.zeros([512, 1]).numpy()
data_2 = tf.zeros([512, 1]).numpy()
data_3 = tf.zeros([512, 1]).numpy()
data_4 = tf.zeros([512, 1]).numpy()
data_frames = [ data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4 ]

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

checkpoint_clusters_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_Cluster_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_clusters_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_clusters_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
if not exists(checkpoint_clusters_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_clusters_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_clusters_dir)
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def animate( i ):
    global CHUNK
    global RATE
    global n_steps
    global data_frames
    
    data = stream.read( CHUNK )
    audio_data = tf.io.decode_raw(tf.constant( data ), tf.int32)
    audio_data = tf.round( audio_data )
    audio_data = tf.cast( audio_data, dtype=tf.float32 )
    
    data_frames = append_data_frames( audio_data, data_frames )
    temp = extract_data_frames( data_frames )
    stfts = tf.signal.stft(temp, frame_length=256, frame_step=64, fft_length=256)
    spectrograms = tf.abs(stfts)
    
    num_spectrogram_bins = stfts.shape[-1]
    lower_edge_hertz, upper_edge_hertz, num_mel_bins = 80.0, 7600.0, 80
    linear_to_mel_weight_matrix = tf.signal.linear_to_mel_weight_matrix( num_mel_bins, num_spectrogram_bins, int( RATE * 2 ), lower_edge_hertz, upper_edge_hertz)
    mel_spectrograms = tf.tensordot( spectrograms, linear_to_mel_weight_matrix, 1)
    mel_spectrograms.set_shape(spectrograms.shape[:-1].concatenate( linear_to_mel_weight_matrix.shape[-1:]) )
    mel_spectrograms = tf.expand_dims(mel_spectrograms, 2)
    
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        mel_spectrograms,
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    
    result = predict_action( mel_spectrograms )
    cluster = predict_cluster( mel_spectrograms )
    im.set_array( image )

    plt.xlabel( str( result + 1 ) + " : " + str( cluster + 1 ), fontsize=22 )
    plt.show()
    
    if n_steps % 8 == 0 :
    
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant([mel_spectrograms.numpy()], shape=(1, 1, 5, 80, 1), dtype=tf.float32),tf.constant([result], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))
        history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=5 ,validation_data=(dataset), callbacks=[custom_callback])
        model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)
    
    if n_steps % 24 == 0 :
    
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant([mel_spectrograms.numpy()], shape=(1, 1, 5, 80, 1), dtype=tf.float32),tf.constant([cluster], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))
        history = model_clusters.fit(dataset, epochs=5 ,validation_data=(dataset), callbacks=[custom_callback])
        model_clusters.save_weights(checkpoint_clusters_path)
        
        
    n_steps = n_steps + 1
    
    return im,

def predict_action( image ) :
    predictions = model.predict(tf.constant(image, shape=(1, 5, 80, 1) , dtype=tf.float32))
    result = tf.math.argmax(predictions[0]).numpy()

    return result

def predict_cluster( image ) :

    predictions = model_clusters.predict(tf.constant(image, shape=(1, 5, 80, 1) , dtype=tf.float32))
    result = tf.math.argmax(predictions[0]).numpy()
    return result

def append_data_frames( data, data_frames ) :   

    data_1 = data_frames[0]
    data_2 = data_frames[1]
    data_3 = data_frames[2]
    data_4 = tf.constant( data, shape=( 512, 1 ) ).numpy()
    data_frames = [ data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4 ]

    return data_frames

def extract_data_frames( data_frames ) :

    temp = tf.stack([data_frames[0], data_frames[1], data_frames[2], data_frames[3]])
    temp = tf.constant( temp, shape=(1, 4 * 512, 1 ))
    predictions = model_frames_extract.predict(temp)
    model_frames_extract.reset_metrics()
    temp = tf.constant( predictions[0], shape=( 512, ))

    return temp

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 5, 80, 1 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((5, 80)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128)),
])
        
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7 * 4))
model.summary()

model_clusters = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 5, 80, 1 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((5, 80)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
])

model_clusters.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model_clusters.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))
model_clusters.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4))
model_clusters.summary()

model_frames_extract = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 512 * 4, 1 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten( ),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
    ])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

fig = plt.figure()
image = plt.imread( "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\cats_name\\train\\Symbols\\01.jpg" )
im = plt.imshow(image)
im.set_cmap('jet')

lable = 0
if im.get_array().shape[0] > 5 :
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.zeros([1, 1, 5, 80, 1]),tf.constant([lable], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))
else :
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant([im.get_array()], shape=(1, 1, 5, 80, 1), dtype=tf.float32),tf.constant([lable], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, patience=0):
        self.best_weights = None
        self.best = 999999999999999
        self.patience = patience
    
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.best = 999999999999999
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if(logs['accuracy'] == None) : 
            pass
        
        if logs['loss'] < self.best :
            self.best = logs['loss']
            self.wait = 0
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else :
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                print("Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.")
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
        
        if logs['loss'] <= 0.2 :
            self.model.stop_training = True

custom_callback = custom_callback(patience=6)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])
model_frames_extract.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])
model_clusters.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1 ,validation_data=(dataset))

model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)
    
while LONG_STEPS > 0:
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=True)
    plt.show()
    
audio.terminate()

print(  "finished recording" )
```